# Deserializing Json var with json.net in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to process a JSON structure with Json.NET but without any luck.

```
{
  "Test": [
    {
      "text": "blah...",
      "Id": 6,
      "Date": "2013-04-13T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "text": "bluuhh...",
      "Id": 7,
      "Date": "2013-02-10T00:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "ErrorCode": 0,
  "Status": 0,
  "StatusString": "Okay",
  "Message": "successfully returned 2 events."
}
```

Usually I write:

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

How is it possible to make a `foreach` for `text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is create objects from json by auto generators [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

for your json it gives

```
public class Test
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Test> Test { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string StatusString { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

then you have

```
RootObject stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
foreach (Test item in stuff.Test)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Or you can generate a class directly in VS2012 in the edit menu => paste special => paste json as classes http://www.guillaumebrout.fr/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/clip_image0011.png

Answer (score 3):

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in stuff.Test)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", item.text, item.Id, item.Date);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :-) Why use {0} {1} {2}? and how to write it with literal

Comment: @user2761009 Just to format the output of *Console.WriteLine* (If find it easier to read then `a + " " + b " " c`). If you like: `var text = (string)item.text;`